# Which is the proper way to read a file in read mode

Tags: python, file, io

I am trying to read a file in read mode. I can do that in two ways

## 1st way

file = open('filename', 'r')

content = file.read()

file.close()

## 2nd way

content = open('filename', 'r').read()

Both codes provide the expected results. I want to know the best way to read a file in read mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to use a context manager so the file is always closed at the end of the context manager scope:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between the three methods?

Comment: @HelloWorld, The difference is that in the first method is correct but you are manually closing the file. In the second method you forgot to close the file what can lead to errors forward in the code.
With this method python handles the closing for you, `with` is your friend here.